# VideoCapture with OpenCV for Android

Tags: android, opencv, video-capture

I want to develop an Android app with [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) to measure my heart rate (finger on sensor). As I could figure out with use of org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture, I only get 8-10 frames per second (fps).

How can I get a higher fps-rate?

I do not want to display the image, I (only) want to record for 15 seconds, resize it with a pyramid (five times) and store it into a `cv::Mat` for further processing. Is there a way to receive 25-30 fps and how do I transfer it frame-by-frame into a `cv::Mat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely do not need 25-30 fps.

The [Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) (AKA [Kotelnikov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Kotelnikov) sampling theorem) tells us:

> If a function x(t) contains no frequencies higher than B hertz, it is completely determined by giving its ordinates at a series of points spaced 1/(2B) seconds apart.

If the heart rate is approximately 1 Hz, it means that you need about 2 Hz sampling rate.

Take a look at: http://adblogcat.com/a-camera-preview-with-a-bounding-box-like-google-goggles/. It gives quite a smooth video preview and you can select ROI.

Comment: I already know that. Thanks. But I want to have 25-30 frames per second as I want to do several things with those videos.

Comment: I did took a look at your suggestion but could manage it with the new OCV version. Now I get around 30fps without any imageprocessing. It seems like opencv version 2.4.8 is working faster or its the android update.